# My Kali Linux screen goes black after I login after installing virtual box guest additions

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, fullscreen

I installed Kali Linux 2020.2 in virtual box 6.1.12. **I was trying to open Kali Linux in full screen on virtual box** so I **gave following commands in chronological order with root** access --

```
apt-get Install linux-headers-686-pae
apt-get install Linux-headers-$(uname -r)
reboot
apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
reboot
```

**uname -r = 5.5.0-kali2-686-pae**

I had update my sources directory. And when I login after this, my screen goes black. How can I fix this issue or I will have to install the OS again ?

Comment: Check out this answer from Ask Ubuntu:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093068/ubuntu-18-10-guest-virtualbox-black-screen-after-install-guest-additions-and

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and using following this steps, I was able to resolving it:

First open a console on `tty2` by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + F2` and login to your account.

After that go to the VM's menu bar and select `Devices -> Optical Drivers -> Choose/Create a Disk Image`. Then click `Add`, go to `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` and select the `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` file to insert Guest Additions media.

Now run the following commands:

```
sudo apt install -y dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
sudo /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after a working Kali Linux in VirtualBox 6.1.30 was updated to VirtualBox 6.1.34.

- Black screen and reloading kernel headers and the guest extensions did nothing to solve.
- Had to back out of the kernel 5.16.0-kali7-amd64 and back to 5.15.0-kali3-amd64.

The dead giveaway is that you'll see, after the guest extensions activate and increase screen size you'll get a second logon screen with the new kernal, then a black screen after logon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but i resolved with just :

On the login screen select option (right bottom) and choose gnome classic.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem and for me it was a very easy fix. When we all use Kali linux for the first time the print is very small so we navigate to view then down to where it says virtual screen 1 and change it to 200%. For some reason the second time you load Kali it does not load 200% you get a blank screen so all you have to do is navigate to view virtual screen 1 and change that back to 100% then after that loads you can switch it back to 200% so you can read everything.